# Is it possible to fully Monkey Patch builtin `str` in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, monkeypatching

I am trying to patch python’s built-in `str` in order to track the count of all `str` allocations.  I am running into some issues and was wondering if anyone could see what I’m doing wrong, or if this is even possible natively through monkey patching in python3? (the following works fine in python 2.7.12)

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
```

I first naively tried to patch `str` as if it were a function:

```
def patch_str_allocations():
  old_str = str
  def mystr(*args, **kwargs):
    return old_str(*args, **kwargs)

  builtins.str = mystr


def test():
  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
  patch_str_allocations()
  logger.debug(str('test'))
```

But of course this fails all sorts of operations that string is used for like `isinstance`

```
    logger.debug(route)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1267, in debug
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1403, in _log
    fn, lno, func, sinfo = self.findCaller(stack_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1360, in findCaller
    filename = os.path.normcase(co.co_filename)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 52, in normcase
    if not isinstance(s, (bytes, str)):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I then tried a class based approach:

```
class StrAllocator(str):
    oldstr = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return StrAllocator.oldstr.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return str


def patch_str_allocations():
    StrAllocator.oldstr = str
    builtins.str = StrAllocator
```

In normal str construction this is working OK but am still running into some issues:

```
class StrAllocatorTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_log(self):
        t1 = str('t1')
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        patch_str_allocations()
        t2 = str('t2')
        print(type(t1))
        print(type(t2))
        print(isinstance(t1, str))
        print(isinstance(t2, StrAllocator))
        print(isinstance(t2, str))
        logger.debug(str('test'))


$ nosetests tests.test_str_allocator:StrAllocatorTestCase.test_log -s

<class 'str'>
<class 'pythonapm.instruments.allocations.StrAllocator'>
False
True
True
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_log (tests.instruments.test_str_allocator.StrAllocatorTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant_data/github.com/dm03514/python-apm/tests/instruments/test_str_allocator.py", line 30, in test_log
    logger.debug(str('test'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1267, in debug
    self._log(DEBUG, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1403, in _log
    fn, lno, func, sinfo = self.findCaller(stack_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1360, in findCaller
    filename = os.path.normcase(co.co_filename)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 54, in normcase
    "not '{}'".format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: normcase() argument must be str or bytes, not 'str'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s
```

As well as in sre_compile on `isstring` check

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1250, in decorator                                                         [0/9965]
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1216, in add_url_rule
    self.url_map.add(rule)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1215, in add
    rule.bind(self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 687, in bind
    self.compile()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 751, in compile
    self._regex = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 224, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/papm/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 292, in _compile
    raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

---

Can anyone see what's missing? (besides my understanding of descriptors and python classes :p )

---

From the REPL the example above Works, but it does not work within the context of nose and unittests...

```
⟫ ipython
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import logging

In [2]: import builtins

In [3]: class StrAllocator(str):
   ...:     oldstr = None
   ...:
   ...:     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
   ...:         return StrAllocator.oldstr.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   ...:
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def __class__(self):
   ...:         return str
   ...:
   ...:
In [4]: def patch_str_allocations():                                                                                                                                    [6/9733]
   ...:     StrAllocator.oldstr = str
   ...:     builtins.str = StrAllocator
   ...:

In [5]:   def test_log():
   ...:         t1 = str('t1')
   ...:         logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
   ...:         patch_str_allocations()
   ...:         t2 = str('t2')
   ...:         print(type(t1))
   ...:         print(type(t2))
   ...:         print(isinstance(t1, str))
   ...:         print(isinstance(t2, StrAllocator))
   ...:         print(isinstance(t2, str))
   ...:         logger.debug(str('test'))
   ...:
In [6]: test_log()
<class 'str'>
<class '__main__.StrAllocator'>
False
True
True
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that TypeError. Could you throw out those `Surfacers` thingies and provide a real MCVE?

Comment: By the way, overriding `str` won't affect string literals and most builtin functions. (For example, `str.join` will create a new string without ever calling your overridden `str`.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey updated also with REPL example, weirdly it's working for me directly in ipython shell

Comment: @dm03514, you have listed the problem but never mentioned your use-case? There may be a different/better way to solve the problem may be

Comment: @TarunLalwani i am attempting to track the count of all str allocations through the builtin `str` method, I"m hoping to increment a counter whenever `str()` is called

Comment: @dm03514 But why? Just curious?

Comment: What you are missing: All strings created **before** you patched now fail the `isinstance()` tests..

Comment: @dm03514: what were you hoping to achieve with counting `str()` calls? There are a large number of operations that can produce strings, so you are not going to track the number of strings created in a Python program using this method. Think `str.format()`, `str.join()`, `%` formatting, string literals, etc. None of those methods call the `str()` built-in to produce those new objects.

Comment: @dm03514 To Martijn's point, I have a hunch that you can get the number you want from the output of `cProfile`. At least that should be a more reliable estimate than monkey patching `str()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on monkey-patching the built-in `str` with your own function, why don't you monkey-patch the `isinstance()` as well to ensure it treats your function as the built-in `str`? Something like:

```
def patch_str_allocations():
    old_str = str
    old_isinstance = builtins.isinstance

    def mystr(*args, **kwargs):
        return old_str(*args, **kwargs)

    def my_isinstance(o, t):
        if t is mystr:
            t = old_str
        return old_isinstance(o, t)

    builtins.str = mystr
    builtins.isinstance = my_isinstance
```

You may also want to check if `t` of `my_isinstance()` is a tuple and iterate over it to make sure you replace `mystr` with `old_str` as well.